# How to inject services into a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, angular-services

I tried to use Angular boostrap-ui in a directive but it didn't work, so I decided to use a service which will use the Angular bootstarp-ui , and to inject it into directive. 
I'm keep getting this error :

> Unknown provider: ui.bootstrapProvider <- ui.bootstrap <- modal <- monitorCardDirective

The Angular app :

```
    'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ,'restangular']);

app.controller('nav', function($scope, $uibModal, $filter, Restangular) {
        $scope.search = false;
});

app.directive('monitorCard',['modal',function(modal) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('click',function(){
                modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'monitoController.html',
                    controller: 'monitorController'
                });
            });
        },
        scope:{
            monitorCard: '='
        }
    };
}]);

app.factory('modal',['ui.bootstrap',function($uibModal){
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'monitoController.html',
        controller: 'monitorController'
    });
    return modalInstance;
}]);
```

Comment: Have you included the necessary <script> file references in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I have included the necessary file in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of your `modal` factory, replace:

```
app.factory('modal', ['ui.bootstrap', function($uibModal)
```

with

```
app.factory('modal', ['$uibModal', function($uibModal)
```

As a side note, notice this factory returns a modal instance. A modal instance object is not a modal service and doesn't have an `open` method, so you will get another error. Judging at the directive you are defining, it seems you just need to inject `uibModal` service in the directive.